# Why Fatal error: Unexpectedly found NIL while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, function, date, null, unwrapping

I would like to read metadata from a video. The console shows me the creation date from the metadata of the file. I may be extracting the date (via string) incorrectly. Why do I get the fatal error? Thank you very much!

```
    func getVideoMetadataDate (srcPath: String, itemSrc: String) async -> Date {
        
        let dF = DateFormatter()
        dF.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"
        
        let returnValue: String = "1975:01:01 00:00:00"
        
        
        let itemSrcURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: srcPath + "/" + String(itemSrc))
        let asset = AVAsset(url: itemSrcURL)
        
        do {
            for format in try await asset.load(.availableMetadataFormats) {
                
                let metadata = try await asset.loadMetadata(for: format)

                let dateItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata, filteredByIdentifier: .commonIdentifierCreationDate)
                guard let item = dateItems.first else { return dF.date(from: returnValue)! }
                let dateCreate = item.value as! String
                print(dateCreate) // Console -> = "2024-02-13T13:22:30+0100"
                return dF.date(from: dateCreate)! // Here -> Thread 9: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            }
        } catch {
            return dF.date(from: returnValue)!
        }
        return dF.date(from: returnValue)!
    }
```

I would like the function to return the creation date from the metadata.

Comment: Your `dateCreate` string has a format that your `DF` can't parse. The main issue I see is that `T` (where you expected a space). By using `!`, you've asked the compiler to assert that your resulting value is not nil, and to crash if it is. It was nil, so it crashed, just as you requested

Comment: Thank you! I think I have understood. Wrong format of the date formatter.

Comment: dF.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call the `!` force unwrap operator the "crash if nil" operator. That is what it does. Any time you use it and the optional you are force-unwrapping contains a nil, your app will crash. You should avoid it completely until you really, really understand optionals, and then probably still avoid it.

As Alexander says in his comment, your input date string does not appear to match the format you've given your DateFormatter. Code that depends on the format of external data is especially fragile, and you should really, REALLY avoid force-unwrapping code that relies on input data formatting.

Look into `if let`, `guard let`, the `??` "nil coalescing operator", and other techniques for safely dealing with nil optionals. Even if you fix your date formatter problem I would still suggest getting rid of the force unwrap and using one of those other techniques (or even making your date field an Optional that is nil if your code can't parse the date correctly, and then coding defensively elsewhere.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! I'll be honest, I haven't worked with the dateformatter for a long time. I thought it would be a bit more robust when parsing and formatting :-/

Comment: DateFormatters are rich, but very picky. The date string you feed them needs to match your format EXACTLY. I suggest feeding a sample date string into it and seeing if you get Date back from it. If you get nil, one trick is to print the current date using your date formatter's `string(from:Date)` and then VERY carefully, character-by-character, compare the format of your output to a sample date that's failing.